# How to make a Windows Form application run automatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have a Windows Form application in C# that right now is working by clicking a button. How I can make it run automatically every 1 minute?

I have added a timer and tried to run Form1 from Main and also I put the code in the Form_Load but it is not running.

Program.cs code:

```
private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

    // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
    aTimer.Interval = 2000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Form1.cs :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = GetApprecord();
    GetDecisionrecord();
    GetRecordFromBothTable();
    passXML(xml);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered by [Gent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241698/gent), you can use a timer to do something at a preset interval. I would recommend using [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), as it is the most accurate, but you may also choose to use the [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) instead.

You can implement a `System.Timers.Timer` with this:

```
private static System.Timers.Timer timer;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(); // Create a new timer instance
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Button1_Click); // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
    timer.AutoReset = true; // Instruct the timer to restart every time the Elapsed event has been called                
    timer.SynchronizingObject = this; // Synchronize the timer with this form UI (IMPORTANT)
    timer.Interval = 1000; // Set the interval to 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
    timer.Enabled = true; // Start the timer
}
```

You can learn more about timers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdzx8wx8.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

you could use a timer, and have buttons that start and stop it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
 aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

 // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
 aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

 // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
 aTimer.Interval = 2000;
 aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: thanks, but not sure why it is not running. I have updated my code at the top.

Comment: @nikta Give my code a try, you need to set some more properties for the timer to work as you intended.

Comment: @JWLim good looking out, thanks for helping I was deep in my code :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Timer` component from the toolbox. It's a simple drop-in that is not drawn and you can set both timing and event that will be fired.